# How to load css files while redirecting a page in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, redirect

I am using CodeIgniter and I want to access a controller method as:

when I load the project as:

http://localhost/CR_Online/

it accesses all the bootstrap theme CSS files and show the default controller function view.

But using this way
http://localhost/CR_Online/index.php/home_controller/registration

It can't access the bootstrap theme CSS files and load the view without CSS.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: This could be only 1 reason... load your css files and all like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("css/style.css"); ?>">` Assuming your file in `CR_Online/css/style.css`

Comment: this is not working!

my css files are in folder: CR_Online/application/assets/styles

so i can load them as:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("application/assets/styles/style.min.css"); ?>">

Comment: try `http://localhost/CR_Online/application/assets/styles/style.min.css` in browser and let me know if your css is loading fine... And also post your `base_url` value from config...

Comment: Yes it works fine!